# NgbHighlight : Limit to one highlight part by line

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm using NgbHighlight to let the user look into a list.

My issue is with the Highlighting of the result.
I want to only have the first match highlighted.

I use the very basics as described here : https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples

Code: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/typeahead/http/stackblitz.html

List : `['ABCD AAAA ABCD', 'BBBB ABCD BBBB', 'CCCC CCCC CCCC'];`

Search : `'ABCD'`

The output I want :

```
'**ABCD** AAAA ABCD'
'BBBB **ABCD** BBBB'
```

The output I get :

```
'**ABCD** AAAA **ABCD**'
'BBBB **ABCD** BBBB'
```

What should I do to limit the highlight to the first part ?

Example:

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="typeahead-http">Search for a wiki page:</label>
  <input id="typeahead-http" type="text" class="form-control" [class.is-invalid]="searchFailed" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" placeholder="Wikipedia search" />
  <span *ngIf="searching">searching...</span>
  <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="searchFailed">Sorry, suggestions could not be loaded.</div>
</div>
```

TypeScript

```
import {Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, map, tap, switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

const WIKI_URL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php';
const PARAMS = new HttpParams({
  fromObject: {
    action: 'opensearch',
    format: 'json',
    origin: '*'
  }
});

@Injectable()
export class WikipediaService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  search(term: string) {
    if (term === '') {
      return of([]);
    }

    return this.http
      .get(WIKI_URL, {params: PARAMS.set('search', term)}).pipe(
        map(response => response[1])
      );
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-typeahead-http',
  templateUrl: './typeahead-http.html',
  providers: [WikipediaService],
  styles: [`.form-control { width: 300px; display: inline; }`]
})
export class NgbdTypeaheadHttp {
  model: any;
  searching = false;
  searchFailed = false;

  constructor(private _service: WikipediaService) {}

  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(() => this.searching = true),
      switchMap(term =>
        this._service.search(term).pipe(
          tap(() => this.searchFailed = false),
          catchError(() => {
            this.searchFailed = true;
            return of([]);
          }))
      ),
      tap(() => this.searching = false)
    )
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code to share?

Comment: Here for exemple : https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/typeahead/http/stackblitz.html

Comment: Link is broken and leads to stackblitz root. Please edit your post to contain the code you are asking about. You may want to have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Should be good now. I copied the wrong link *facepalm*
I'm going to edit to add a few line of code. But as I sayed, I'm using the basic implémentation as discribed in the first link. (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to avoid touching the code of ngb-typeahead I've made a "fix" on my CSS.
Not the pretiest solution, but at least it's working visually.

Here is the generated HTML by ngb-typeahead (untouched, I just removed the comments).
Search term : 'ABCD'

```
<ngb-highlight ng-reflect-result="'ABCD AAAA ABCD" ng-reflect-term="act">
    <span class="ngb-highlight">ABCD</span>
    &nbsp;AAAA&nbsp;
    <span class="ngb-highlight">ABCD</span>
</ngb-highlight>
```

So my solution :

```
.ngb-highlight {
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

ngb-highlight .ngb-highlight:first-child {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

As you can see, not the prettiest but at least I don't have to modify anything that could be override in the futur.

Anyway, thx for your help everyone !

Answer (score 0):

NgbHighlight cannot do it. You can easily implement the component you need based on [NgbHighlight source code](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/highlight.ts). It's a tiny component and a small change. You just need to change regex a bit to split only on the first occurrence of a term

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const result = toString(this.result);

    const terms = Array.isArray(this.term) ? this.term : [this.term];
    const escapedTerms = terms.map(term => regExpEscape(toString(term)))
        .map(term => `${term}(.+)`)
        .filter(term => term);


    this.parts = escapedTerms.length ? result.split(new RegExp(`(${escapedTerms.join('|')})`, 'gmi')) : [result];
  }
```

the code was never tested (: not sure if it will work with several terms

Comment: As that would force me to change a lot more than I'm prepare to (either re-implement the full typeahead or directly modify ng-bootstrap and risk override at each update), I proposed an other solution.
But thx a lot for your help !
Trully appreciated :)